# Kotlin Android - Databinding fail in my fragment

Tags: android, binding, kotlin

When I build the application (build, but not yet run), 
I encounter build error:

> Found databinding error....cannot find method
>   addTask(java.lang.String,boolean) in class
>   com.edenhan.simplytask.CreateTaskForm.

But I did have addTask method into this `CreateTaskForm` kotlin class, so not sure what went wrong.

Below is the fragment class, CreateTaskForm,

```
class CreateTaskForm:Fragment (){

var addTask:(String,Boolean)-> Unit={s,b-> }

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, 
savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

var binding:FragmentCreateTaskFormBinding = 
 DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_create_task_form, container,false)
        binding.me=this
        return binding.root

    }
```

Below is the fragment layout fragment_create_task_form

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable name="me" type="com.edenhan.simplytask.CreateTaskForm">
       </variable>
</data>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCreateTask"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
            android:onClick="@{(v)->me.addTask(`ds`,true)}"
            .../>
```

Comment: Have you tried to just Rebuild your app?

Comment: var addTask:(String,Boolean)-> Unit={s,b-> } 
Shouldn't it be function?

Comment: I have seen kind of similar thing here https://instil.co/2018/01/15/android-databind-kotlin/

Comment: Hi Sagar, thanks for reply. Yes. I have clean and rebuild. Still same error

Comment: Hi TapanHP. Thanks for reply. Yes. addTask is a function. It will ultimately be set with an actual implementation from the main activity. Thanks for the URL, I will now take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Found databinding error....cannot find method
>   addTask(java.lang.String,boolean) in class
>   com.edenhan.simplytask.CreateTaskForm.

Databinding can't find method in CreateTaskForm, probably doesn't recognize your class function field as class method.

> var addTask:(String,Boolean)-> Unit={s,b-> }

I see two solution:

First, change field to function in CreateTaskForm:

```
fun addTask(value: String, flag: Boolean) {
}
```

Second, direct invocation from function field in xml:

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCreateTask"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:onClick="@{(v)->me.addTask.invoke(`ds`,true)}"
        .../>
```

Comment: Yes. Its working, after changing field to function. But curious, why would  a field containing a function not work. Is this android limitation? The reason why i need a field to hold a function, is because this field will be set by the main activity.

Comment: You can keep field with function, just have to direct invocation function from field me.addTask.invoke(`ds`,true), because Android autogenerated code doesn't know about Kotlin function fields.

Comment: Hi. Thanks, I think your second solution is working for me! look like I really need to use the invoke function. The first solution is not required.